# AWS EC-2 changed time and 403 forbidden error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timezone, http-status-code-403

I have an EC-2 AWS instance.
It has already an elastic IP, connected with a domain, that I used to reach some .php files.

Some days ago I changed the time in this way (Server in USA and I live in Germany):

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
cd /usr/share/zoneinfo
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/DE /etc/localtime
```

It worked perfectly, but since some days I cannot reach my php files anymore. I receive a `403 Forbidden` error.

It could be the reason of the error? Or should I look for something else? How can I solve it?

EDIT:
I've read into the log, and the error says:

```
AH00035: access denied by server configuration
```

I edited my `.conf` file like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I changed the permissions with:

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

without success.

Comment: Review the logs.  Until then, it's guesswork, but changing the time zone on a server to use something other than UTC is not usually a good idea.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, and probably belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser.  Also, `DE` is a country code, not a time zone.  If you wanted the time zone for Germany, specify `Europe/Berlin`.

Comment: Actually I reset the timezone to UTC, and the 403 error is still there. There is probabli something else that cause the error.